# How to aggregate data per day on spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark

My problem is the following:
I have to write a scala program for spark streaming, this program has to read data from a kafka topic and save it in a cassandra table.
My data is of the form:

transaction_id,customer_id,merchant_id,status,timestamp,invoice_no,invoice_amount
202207280000001,1966,319,SUCCESS,07/28/22,835-975-389,86562

The need is to aggregate the data by day and to count by amount (between 0 and 500, between 500 and 1000, between 1000 and 1500, and over 2000).

Can someone help me?
Thanks

OK let me try to be more clear.
A spark streaming application written in scala, which has to read data from a Kafka topic, the data is structured in the following way:
transaction_id,customer_id,merchant_id,status,timestamp,invoice_no,invoice_amount
Example (fictitious data):
202207280000001,1966,319,SUCCESS,07/28/22,835-975-389,86562
202207280000002,1970,320,SUCCESS,07/28/22,835-980-395,50000
202207280000003,1966,319,SUCCESS,07/28/22,835-975-399,200
202207280000004,658,400,SUCCESS,07/25/22,835-975-200,800
202207280000005,1966,319,SUCCESS,07/25/22,835-975-387,300

From these data I have to calculate in real time the Count of transaction happened falling in price bucket 0-500, 0-1000, 0-2000, and over 2000.
The displayed result would be for example :

07/28/22 | Below500 | 1
07/28/22 | Below1000 | 0
07/28/22 | Below1500 | 0
07/28/22 | Above2000 |2
07/25/22 | Below500 | 1
07/25/22 | Below1000 | 1
07/25/22 | Below1500 | 0
07/25/22 | Above2000 | 0

My program reads the topic well and displays the data coming from Kafka but I can't process the data to display the right result.
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have just added more details